# XCode build of kivy app fails with Syntax Errors

Tags: python, xcode, kivy

I've been working with python for a couple years now and started using kivy to build a little iOS app. It was fun, but now I'm stuck at making the build in XCode and after retrying several times with different environments etc. I don't have a single clue on how to continue.

The errors I get are like this:

```
Compiling '/Users/<myuser>/<myappname>/YourApp/build/python3/x86_64/Python-3.9.9/Tools/test2to3/maintest.py'...
***   File "/Users/<myuser>/<myappname>/YourApp/build/python3/x86_64/Python-3.9.9/Tools/test2to3/maintest.py", line 8
    except ImportError, e:
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

and

```
***   File "/Users/<myuser>/<myappname>/YourApp/build/python3/x86_64/Python-3.9.9/Tools/test2to3/test2to3/hello.py", line 3
    print "Hello, world"
          ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print("Hello, world")?
```

From what I understand that should be typical error when trying to run code using python2 syntax (e.g. print without parentheses) in python3. The location seems to me like it must be some kind of tests in python3 (for compatibility with python2?). I don't think it's code I need, but Xcode somehow seems to include it in the build and therefor fails.
Can someone explain why this is included and how to get rid of it? Or is it something else that's wrong here?

(I followed [this guide](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/packaging-ios.html), made sure to use a venv with python3 and only installed necessary libraries (numpy, kivy), also made sure to have that venv active when I ran `toolchain build python3 kivy numpy`. Also, I'm using a Mac(M1) in case that matters.)

**Update for others with the same problem:** Unfortunately I didn't manage to fix this, so I learned Swift instead. It's confusing sometimes (at least for me), but I like the result way more than the kivy version before. So before you quit the idea of building an App, maybe try that.